# Replace all 'A' present in an Array with '15' in Swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift

I want to replace all `A` characters present in an array with `15` using Swift 3.

Example array:

```
["4", "5", "6", "A", "A", "Q", "A"]
```

Desired result:

```
["4", "5", "6", "15", "15", "Q", "15"]
```

Comment: You must have tried something. Don't hesitate to show your attempt, so that it does not look like a *"give me the code"* question!

Comment: I am trying this code

var a = ["4", "5", "6", "A", "A", "Q", "A"]
   
                                                                                                                   
    a = a.map {$0 == "A" ? "15" : $0}

for the desired result but i am getting "Result values in '? :' expression have mismatching types 'String' and 'Character" This error

Comment: So you needed to show at least this code. And there is an error message, so we may help you explaining why you get it, and how to fix it.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/hfscwn   
This is the error message what i am getting.

Comment: My array is Array for characters and not Array of strings.

Comment: How can a Question become ( -4 ) ??? I mean, it's a question - a person trying to figure out something he(she) doesn't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[map](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2908681-map) to the rescue:

```
var a = ["4", "5", "6", "A", "A", "Q", "A"]
a = a.map({ $0 == "A" ? "15" : $0 })
print(a)// ["4", "5", "6", "15", "15", "Q", "15"]
```

**EDIT:** After error screenshot:

You have an array of characters and hence the above code is not working. Also, remember "15" is two characters and not one character. Hence, I have replaced character 'A' with string "15" and mapped it to an array of strings, instead

```
let player1 = "456AAQA"
var player1Cards = Array(player1.characters) // ["4", "5", "6", "A", "A", "Q", "A"]

var player1CardsStrings = player1Cards.map{$0 == "A" ? "15" : String($0)}

player1CardsStrings // ["4", "5", "6", "15", "15", "Q", "15"]
```

Comment: Result values in '? :' expression have mismatching types 'String' and 'Character'...Its giving me this error.

Comment: @NeerajSonaro: This code is working for both Swift 3 and 4 in my tests. Which version of XCode are you using?

Comment: @NeerajSonaro: Try this var a:[String] = ["4", "5", "6", "A", "A", "Q", "A"]
a = a.map {$0 == String("A") ? String("15") : $0}

Comment: You have to put in `()` if you want to use shorthand -> `({ $0 == "A" ? "15" : $0 })`

Comment: @Tj3n: Actually, no. map syntax works without() brackets as well.

Comment: @NeerajSonaro: Not able to understand you. How have you got to String using the above code?

Comment: yes yes...I got...Thanks @ Puneet Sharma for your Help :)

Answer (score 1):

Tested on Playground.

Because your question is lacking information that you didn't gave at first, here is what you can do.

"for loop": You iterate and replace the value if needed.
That's a logic you could apply on almost all languages.

```
var array1 = ["4", "5", "6", "A", "A", "Q", "A"]
for index in 0 ... array1.count-1
{
    if array1[index] == "A"
    {
        array1[index] = "15"
    }
}
print("array1: \(array1)")
```

"for each loop": You iterate and replace the value if needed.
That's a logic you could apply on almost all languages (maybe less languages that the previous one)

```
var array2 = ["4", "5", "6", "A", "A", "Q", "A"]
for (index, object) in array2.enumerated()
{
    if object == "A"
    {
        array2[index] = "15"
    }
}
print("array2: \(array2)")
```

"map": the "map" iterate for you (here is the important part behind the magic), you check the value and replace the value if needed. The `$0` represent the "current item".
Here is a specificity.

```
var array3 = ["4", "5", "6", "A", "A", "Q", "A"]
array3 = array3.map({
    if $0 == "A"
    {
        return "15"
    }
    return $0
})
print("array3: \(array3)")
```

"map": the "map" iterate for you, you check the value and replace the value if needed with a ternary if test.

```
var array4 = ["4", "5", "6", "A", "A", "Q", "A"]
array4 = array4.map({$0 == "A" ? "15" : $0})
print("array4: \(array4)")
```

I'm gave 4 ways (I've could also have explicit more the `map()` with explicit closure, from the simplest to the more complicated. We can't know if you don't show your attempts where you are are stucked. Is it for loop? The basic algorithms? 
Swift advanced user may be more fond of the last one, but for beginners, it's quite complex and "magic". So when they want to change it a little for a different test, they never know what to do.

Side note: I'm not a Swift developer, more an Objective-C, so it may be lacking of checks. This answers is to show different approaches, how you go from a "verbose" to a less "verbose" code, but that you need to master anyway. Even if you have issue with `map()`, you can "bypass" it and do it manually.

Comment: i tried your code @Larme...But i am getting this isse "Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'Character'". I have tried every thing but i am not able to understand why the hell i am getting this isse.

Comment: Your array is created how? How is it populated? I’d say that one of the value of the array is a Character not a String...

Comment: i have a string which i am converting to array like   var player1Cards = Array(player1.characters) this.  where player1 is String.

Comment: So play1Cards is an array of Characters, not an array of String. That should be an IMPORTANT information that you should put on your question, edit it! As such your attempt and the error!

Answer (score 0):

```
 let values = ["4", "5", "6", "A", "A", "Q", "A"]
 let mappedvalues = values.map({ (value: String) -> String in
    if value != "A" {
       return value
    }
    return "15"
 })
```